# jboss 5.1: How to share session between multiple wars

Tags: java, jsp, session, jboss5.x

I have multiple wars deployed in the same Jboss instance.
One of the wars will be hosting a Login page that will let the user sign in.
on sign in, the system creates a User Session. Now, the user tries to navigate another module 'http://site/notsigninmodule' the user session should be still available to the 'notsigninmodule' app.

Does anyone know how to achieve this? An example would be most useful

Comment: See https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/JBossWebSingleSignOn and https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_JBoss_Portal/5.1/html/Reference_Guide/ch14s07s02.html

Comment: The SSO mechanism, allows the user to sign in to a second web-app without reauthentication, but creates a new Http session object. Isn't this the case ?

Answer (score 2):

After days of research, this is what i came up with

Sharing sessions between web applications would violate the JavaEE Servlet specification,apparently.

"Session information is scoped only to the current web application (ServletContext), so information stored in one context will not be directly visible in another"

In 2013/2014 The following feature request JIRAs were opened for community versions.

https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBAS-9545
https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFLY-1891

Now, in the community version wildfly 9 This feature is available: https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY9/Web+(Undertow)+Reference+Guide

So my conclusion is that in jboss 5.1, i cannot achieve my rqm. 
I opted to bringing in the jsp pages into the web app that creates the session.